# Surprising noun order involving the の particle

Tags: particle-の

I am puzzled by the word ordering in the following sentence:

> そのうちの一つの[箱]{はこ}は私のです。

This sounds unnatural to me, though I was told that this is correct by a native speaker (who was not able to explain why). Whenever I've encountered this linking/nominalization/possessive particle before, the nouns were ordered with increasing specificity. (e.g. 友達の本の名前).

Based on that principle, I would have expected the sentence to read

> その[箱]{はこ}のうちの一つは私のです。

I.e.:

1. most general: 箱 (box(es)),
2. more specific 箱のうち (amongst the boxes)
3. most specific: 箱のうちの一つ (one of the boxes)

What am I missing?

Comment: A hotel guest says this to the staff in front of a big heap of luggage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, I think there are two acceptable ways to say this in English, too:

> そのうちの一つの箱は私のです。
>   One box among those is mine. (more literally) Among those, one box is mine.
>
> その箱のうちの一つは私のです。
>   One of those boxes is mine.

It's true the former looks slightly less-organized, but the nuance is fairly small in spoken language.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, my interpretation of "そのうち" in this case would be "among those things".  Hence, it's referring to a collection of non-descript items that also happens to include a box among them.

Comment: I agree and would not have found this sentence awkward if it read そのうちの箱。 But it seems strange to single out "one non-descript item" (そのうちの一つ) and then make it specific by saying that it's a box.

Comment: In that regard, it's not uncommon to use a relatively generic counter (especially if there isn't a particularly specific one for it) and then clarify what it is (cf. 七人【しちにん】の侍【さむらい】).